# How to check if anything was chosen in a File Input

Tags: php, forms, file, input, upload

so i have this form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="pics"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitpic">
</form>
```

while trying to identify if there is actually a chosen file seems like $_POST['pics'];
doesnt work, or doesnt get a value.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitpic'])){ 
    if($_POST['pics']!=NULL){   
        $dir = 'id_data/';
        $pic_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['pics']['name']);
        $pic_unique_id = $userid;
        $pic_name = $pic_unique_id.".".$pic_ext['extension'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name'],"$dir/$pic_name")){
            echo "yes";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

is there another way to check if a file was chosen?
thanks!

Comment: it's in the files array, below you are using it... your syntax is wrong, you are missing `)` in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can check if file is in the POST request with

```
isset($_FILES['pics'])
```

otherwise

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name'],"$dir/$pic_name")
```

is true when file is moved, so if file is uploaded but for some reason not moved (e.g. due to directory permission), then it will return false anyway.

Comment: Yes, if you declare input field with name "pics", then isset($_FILES['pics']) will return true if file is uploaded.
Here have a piece of code:
`<?php
echo "Uploaded:".isset($_FILES['pics']);
if(isset($_POST['submitpic'])){ 
    if($_POST['pics']!=NULL){   
        $dir = 'id_data/';
        $pic_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['pics']['name']);
        $pic_unique_id = $userid;
        $pic_name = $pic_unique_id.".".$pic_ext['extension'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name'],"$dir/$pic_name")){
            echo "yes";
        }
    }
}
?>`
+ your HTML content

Comment: `isset($_FILES['pics'])` will return true, also if filename is null

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose I will show the following code and it's output after EMPTY submission:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
<input type="file" name="pics"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitpic">
</form>

<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump(isset($_FILES['pics']));
var_dump(empty($_FILES['pics']['name']));

array (size=1)
  'submitpic' => string 'Submit Query' (length=12)

array (size=1)
  'pics' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0

boolean true

boolean true
```

So `pics` is in the `$_FILES` array and it's always true checking `isset()` even it's empty.. You need to check if the `name` is empty. Then you can do:

`if(!empty($_FILES['pics']['name']))` instead of `if($_POST['pics']!=NULL)`. But I bet you need some more validations aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're submitting a 'file', you have to check on your back-end using `$_FILES` check. Here's how:

```
if(isset($_FILE)) 
{
     //Enter your code here.
}
```

Comment: According to my understanding of PHP, the condition will execute only if the $_FILE attribute is set.
Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: The problem here is after submission the form with empty values the array $_FILE will exist, also `pics` will exist in it. And even more, the behavior of $_FILE[] will set keys to `$_FILE['pics]` like `name`, etc, no matter if there's no file name posted

Comment: You can take a look at my answer. I have explained with dumping the posted values, the behavior of this post/file form. `isset($_FILES)` and `isset($_FILE['pics']` returns true with empty submission

Comment: Understood. I'll make sure to follow these suggestions the next time I'm doing playing with `$_FILE` in PHP :)